# Certificate authentication to access an api in java

Tags: python, java, authentication, web-services, security

So I’d like to know the equivalent in Java for the following code in python :

```
requests.get("some url", cert="key.pem")
```

The `key.pem` is composed of an `rsa` key and a certificate. How can I make the same call in Java?

It would help me a lot to have an equivalent in Java.

Comment: What exactly does that Python function does? Is key.pem a certificate or a key-pair?

Comment: @aled the python function is from requests library. It makes a get call to the url given. 
For key.pem as I said, it contains an rsa key and a certificate.

Comment: Is the server requesting TLS mutual authentication?

Comment: No the server only check the key and return the information requested.

Comment: Private keys are not shared with servers. Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

The **HttpURLConnection** class in Java can be used to send an HTTP GET request that includes a certificate file. To fulfil the Python code demands ***requests.get("some url", cert="key.pem")*** requires that the certificate be loaded from the key.pem file, the connection to the URL be established, and the SSL context be configured with the certificate.
The GET request can then be made, followed by reading the response and handling it appropriately. I hope this will help you.